# Can't download anything on Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, download

I have been trying to download files on Google Chrome recently and it completes downloading the file, but when I try to run it, it gives me this error:

`Windows cannot find 'D:\Downloads\minecraft.jar'.  Make sure you typed the name correctly and then try again.`

It's not only this file and I have also tried the same on Firefox.

I rebooted the computer but the problem persists.
Also, the computer wouldn't turn on after being rebooted until I unplugged my USBs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are your downloads set to go to?  `D:\Downloads`?  You can check by following [these instructions](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95574).

Comment: What happens if you choose 'show in folder'? Can you see the file there? If not, can you see it while it is being downloaded (i.e. does it then disappear)?

Comment: While googling around, I found this guy saying that it was because of a virus. As far as I got it, the virus was infecting new download, so the antivirus was deleting those files. Try to download something with your AV off, and if it works, plan a full AV scan at reboot.

Comment: When I choose 'show in folder', no window comes up.

Answer (score 1):

It has been happening to a LOT of people. Someone even put a list of all the places discussing this to make it easier for people to keep track of when someone actually finds a solution. What is known as "the AVG work around" has worked for some but NOT all people. Also some report this only happening with Chrome browsers while a few others have experienced this with other browsers as well. A couple people accuse the latest Windows updates. Cannot verify at this time how people not using Windows are affected.